# Сравнение Kohana и Yii

Tags: yii, kohana

Всем доброго времени суток. Ребят, кто использовал и то, и другое. Расскажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях yii удобней использовать, чем kohana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вечный вопрос. В интернете есть очень много статей про эти фреймворки, очень много сравнений, досконально расписаны все преимущества и недостатки. Конечно, все эти мнения субьективны, но прочитав их Вы сделаете какие-то выводы и выберите самый удобный и подходящий конкретно для Вас фреймворк.
[Почва для размышлений](http://bit.ly/ACzE4r)